# Python Error : expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python

I think the error is coming from the csv file loaded.

codes I used are

```py
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\CCHHR\Advanced-Trading-Analysis-Data.csv')

def TrendStrategyRun1(nfastSMA, nslowSMA, chart):
    instruments = ['SPY']

    feed = csvfeed.GenericBarFeed(bar.Frequency.DAY)
    feed.addBarsFromCSV(
        instruments[0],
        data,
        skipMalformedBars=True
    )

    trendStrategy1 = TrendStrategy(
        feed,
        instrument[0],
        nfastSMA,
        nslowSMA
    )

    trendStrategy1.getBroker().setCommission(
        broker.backtesting.FixedPerTrade(6)
    )

    retAnalyzer = ret.Returns(maxLen=2518)
    trendStrategy1.attachAnalyzer(retAnalyzer)

    plt = plotter.StrategyPlotter(
        trendStrategy1,
        plotPortfolio=False
    )

    plt.getInstrumentSubplot('SPY').addDataSeries(
        'Fast SMA',
        trendStrategy1.getfastSMA()
    )

    plt.getInstrumentSubplot('SPY').addDataSeries(
        'Slow SMA',
        trendStrategy1.getslowSMA()
    )

    trendStrategy1.run()

    datesReturns = retAnalyzer.getReturns().getDateTimes()[:]
    dailyReturns = retAnalyzer.getReturns()[:]
    dailyReturns = pd.DteFrame(dailyReturns).set_index(
        pd.DatetimeIndex(datesReturns)
    )

    if chart == True:
        plt.plot(
            fromDateTime=dt.datetime(2016, 1, 1),
            toDateTime=dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)
        )

    return dailyReturns


TrendStrategyRun1(5, 20, True)
```

and I got the following error message

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Can someone tell me where the error come from?

Thanks alot

Comment: Edit the question to show the full traceback and repair the formatting of the code.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code and post the full error traceback.

Comment: I'm not sure but judging by the error message I guess you need to replace `open(data)` with just `data` as the argument for `feed.addBarsFromCSV()`.

Comment: So now you need to follow Michael's advice and post the full traceback output.

Comment: If you remove `open` then `data` must point to file you want to open and not an object of `pd.read_csv()`... still guessing though.

Comment: Thanks edited and worked perfectly!